Optimizing a MySQL Stored Procedure to get index from Custom Secondary index
Knowing the restrictions on inserting a numbered row in views and not been able return tables from functions in mySQL, I found myself having to use a stored procedure in order to get the index serial value of a row depending of the value of a secondary column.
What we can do normally by select * from table where regular_column=value, I'm trying to transform into what_id(value), where what_id is a stored procedure that creates an index from all records not blank of the main table that corresponds to that column, sort them alphabetically, and assigns them an index number in a new column. I also keep record of what is the original table id of every record on the same index table.
Because is meant to handle a very big table, the procedure creates another table, this table takes the first two characters from every index value column recently created and creates another index, I add an id row to work with the data and the position on the first index table from where it was taken. I group by the index trunced code and set in the last record position it is on the first index table by using max()
The procedure works like this, you CALL what_id('temp20241023'); it creates a first temporary table and fills it with all codes on the main table. Creates the second temporary table and fills it with all first two letters of the first temporary table. Then asks for the position on the first temporary of the two first letter of the asked code, it returns the last position. It asks again for the position of the previous record to get the from range. Then selects the segment that corresponds to the first two characters of the asked value on the first temporary table, and searches for the index position of the value in it.
I leave the code here for review:
CREATE PROCEDURE `what_id`(_userinput varchar(24))
BEGIN
    declare _inputchars varchar(24);
    declare _codigo varchar(24);
    declare _aux int;
    declare _ini int;
    declare _fin int;        
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_indice;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_indice(id_indice INT PRIMARY KEY, indice varchar(2), fin smallint);
    INSERT INTO temp_indice (SELECT @j:=@j + 1 AS id_indice, indice, fin FROM 
    (SELECT substring(codigo, 1, 2) AS indice, max(id_sort) as fin FROM 
        (SELECT @i:=@i + 1 AS id_sort, codigo, idposts FROM 
            select_post,(select @i:=0, @j:=0) 
            as temp) 
        as temp GROUP BY indice) 
    as temp);
    set _inputchars = UPPER(substring(_userinput, 1, 2));
    SELECT id_indice, fin INTO _aux, _fin FROM temp_indice as temp WHERE indice=_inputchars;
    set _aux = _aux-1;
    set _ini := (SELECT fin FROM temp_indice as temp WHERE id_indice = _aux);
    set _ini = _ini+1;
    
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS datos;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE datos(id_sort INT, codigo varchar(24), idposts int);
    INSERT INTO datos (SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT @i:=@i + 1 AS id_sort, codigo, idposts FROM 
        select_post,(select @i:=0) 
        as temp) 
    as temp WHERE id_sort BETWEEN _ini and _fin);
        
    set _codigo := (SELECT idposts FROM datos as temp WHERE codigo=_userinput);
    SELECT * FROM posts WHERE idposts=_codigo limit 1;  
END

Although the code works and returns the record of the main table (posts) where the index corresponds to the resolved code, it takes almost 300ms while just asking to the table by the code directly takes 90ms. Because this code was tested in Postgress with 70ms performance, I'm guessing is the way I'm adapting the code to mySQL and not the code itself. I believe it's the process of creating and dumping information into tables. But putting all the code repeatedly in every consult instead ends up taking about 500ms and not less.
I'm hoping for a easier, simpler, cost efficient way to achieve this

What is MySQL version precisely?

Window functions were introduced in mysql version 8. What version are you on? Please publish the result of select version();

I have my doubts that the published code produces , please add sample data as text.

The report of the hosting reads: mysql (10.6.20-MariaDB-cll-lve.
Salmon I don't understand what you ask, the code of the procedure returns the primary key of the main data table, that is looked up from two auxiliary index tables temporary created to do so, with it selects the data of that id in the main table.
